# jQuery — Nested Sortables Plugin — Disabling sortability between parents

Tags: jquery, sortables

I've got a question that I think is simple but I've not been able to figure it out.

This is in regard to this plugin: http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/

Essentially, I want to disable the ability to sort children outside of their parents.

So, I've got this:

```
CATEGORY 1
      ITEM 1.1
      ITEM 1.2
      ITEM 1.3

CATEGORY 2
      ITEM 2.1
      ITEM 2.2
      ITEM 2.3
```

So, I'd like to provide the ability for users to sort the children within their category, and the ability to sort the categories themselves. But I want to disable the ability to move a child to another parent. (e.g. ITEM 1.1 cannot be moved to CATEGORY 2). And also I would like to disable the abilty to nest any parents in any children.

I tried setting it so that the 'nestedSortable' function is called for every new OL but that simple disables sorting for everything entirely.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answered what is essentially an identical question here:
[jQuery UI: Only allow sortable within its own parent level, and not above or below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892435/jquery-ui-only-allow-sortable-within-its-own-parent-level-and-not-above-or-belo/4892590#4892590)

Comment: Holy Shazbots. Thank you schizo. So simple. I was using the NestedSortable plugin when I didn't even need to. Thanks again, I was pulling my hair out trying to get this to work.