# jQuery Nested Sortable maxDepth option

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using this plugin: http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

(It's not the jQueryUI Sortable. This one is nestable.)

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/kk8k2z8w/)

I'm trying to do this:

The menu should only allow folders in the root.

It shouldn't allow to drag a folder inside another folder.

Unfortunately, this plugin has no maxLevel or Depth option.

What I've done so far was to use the `isValidTarget` function to return true or false. If the dragged item is a `.folder` and the `.placeholder` is inside a `.folder` I return false and it almost works but the problem is that returning false removes the placeholder so it returns true again... (so it's flickering)

```
if($item.hasClass('folder') && $('.placeholder').parent().parent('li').hasClass('folder')){
    return false
}else{
    return true
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Some solutions here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447305/nested-sortable-elements-lock-depth

Comment: Thanks but it has nothing to do with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/kk8k2z8w/1/

Prevents dragging the sub-menu into another sub-menu.

```
menu.sortable({
 isValidTarget: function ($item, container) {
    return !(container.el.parent('li').hasClass('folder') && $item.hasClass('folder'));
 }
});
```